# Insertar Registro - PHP

Tags: php, poo, insert, crud

Estoy intentando insertar un nuevo usuario a mi base de datos y resulta que me sale el siguiente error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cellphone' cannot be null in /home/martyn/WebTaskManager/Repository/UserRepository.php:160
Stack trace:
#0 /home/martyn/WebTaskManager/Repository/UserRepository.php(160): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/martyn/WebTaskManager/Test/Repository/User/UserList.php(66): WTManager\Repository\UserRepository->CreateUser(Object(WTManager\Model\UserModel))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/martyn/WebTaskManager/Repository/UserRepository.php on line 160
```

La función en cuestión es la siguiente, ubicada en el archivo **UserRepository.php**:

```
public function CreateUser( UserModel $user )
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users 
                  SET         user_name  = :user_name,
                              password   = :password,
                              cellphone  = :cellphone,
                              email      = :email,
                              department = :department";      

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( $query );

        $stmt->execute( [

                        ':user_name'    =>  $user->GetUserName(),
                        ':password'     =>  $user->GetPass(),
                        ':cellphone'    =>  $user->GetCellphone(),
                        ':email'        =>  $user->GetEmail(),
                        ':department'   =>  $user->GetDepartment()

                        ]
                    );

        $data = new UserModel();

        $data->SetId( $user['id'] );
        $data->SetUserName( $user['user_name'] );
        $data->SetPass( $user['password'] );
        $data->SetCellphone( $user['cellphone'] );
        $data->SetEmail( $user['email'] );
        $data->SetDepartment( $user['department'] );

        return ( bool ) $stmt->rowCount();                                       

    }
```

Y lo que estoy intentando en el archivo **UserList.php** ubicado en el directorio Test:

```
$addUser = new UserModel( 'Martyn', 12345666, 1126174223, 'martin@gmail.com', 'Office' );

$user = $userRepository->CreateUser( $addUser );
```

PD: Todos los valores por defecto en mi base de datos son **NOT NULL**, aclaro. 
Espero una posible solución, desde ya muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa el método `GetCellphone()` en la clase `UserModel`, pues está devolviendo `NULL` y por eso el error: *`'cellphone' cannot be null`* Puedes verificar los datos con un `var_dump($user);` por ejemplo. Si el método está bien, entonces revisa el orden de los parámetros `'Martyn', 12345666, 1126174223, 'martin@gmail.com', 'Office'`
 y la forma en que seteas cada dato en la clase.